Transitions and exit animations not executing
I'm working on a Gatsby project and decided to use Motion for CSS animations.  As of right now my code looks like this
<AnimatePresence>

    { filterToggle && (

        <motion.article
            key="groupFilter"
            className={ styles.filterContainer }
            initial={{ transform: 'perspective(1000px) translateY(-300px) translateZ(-1000px) rotateX(-90deg)' }}
            animate={{ transform: 'translateZ(0) translateY(0) rotateX(0)' }}
            exit={{ transform: 'perspective(1000) translateZ(-1000px)' }}
            transition={{ type: 'spring', duration: 3, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
        >

            <GroupFilter
                nameList={ createGroupList( organizations ) }
                toggle={ (value) => handleFilterToggle( value ) }
                resultList={ filterGroups }
            />
              
        </motion.article>

    )}

</AnimatePresence>

The element enters accordingly with the initial settings however the spring doesn't seem to work. I tinkered with both the bounce and stiffness properties which doesn't seem to have had any effect.  When I close the element it sits still for a second then flashes away instead of performing the exit animation.  The styling I applied to the <motion.article> element through the filterContainer class looks like this
.filterContainer{

    display          : grid;
    justify-items    : center;
    align-items      : top;
    background-color : hsl( var( --gray-200 ), 1 );
    position         : fixed;
    top              : 0;
    height           : 100vh;
    z-index          : 555;
    width            : 100%;

}

I tried removing the position : fixed; and top : 0; properties to see if maybe they were interfering in some way but I still get the same results.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?
